# How to concatenate the keys and values of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Your team is going camping and you are taking a vote to decide what food to pack for dinner.
>
> Everyone gets a vote and the food item that gets at least one more than half of the votes wins. None of the items wins if nothing gets at least one more than half votes. Assume that every person gets only one vote.
>
> The input will contain a list of food items where each occurrence of an item represents one vote. You should print the winning food item as output. If there is no clear winner, print "NOTA".
>
> ```
> Input1: {'a','b','a','a','b','b'}
> output1: NOTA
>
> Input2: {'a','b','a','a','b','b','b'}
> output2: b
> ```

I have written the code which gives me the count of the repeated values.

```
import ast,sys
input_str = sys.stdin.read()
votes = ast.literal_eval(input_str)
d = {}
for i in votes:
    if i not in d:
        d[i]=1
    else:
        d[i] = d[i]+1
```

Above code give me the count of all repeated values eg for Input1 it returns `dict_values[3,3]`

But I want to concatenate the keys and values together in dictionary.
eg: `{'a': 3, 'b':3}` so that I can make use of the below code.

```
vals = list(d.values())    
for value in vals:
    if value[0]==value[1]:
        print('NOTA')
    else:
        if value[0] > value[1]:
            print(max(d.key()) (something like this)
```

Comment: Note: do not use `sys.stdin.read()`. This will block until the stdin has closed. If you want to get the input the moment the person enters, use `sys.stdin.readline`.

Comment: Or just use `input_str = input()`.

Comment: Your code already returns that dictionary. It sounds like you're printing `d.values()` instead of printing `d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I combined the two functions and fixed the code a little:

```py
import ast,sys
input_str = sys.stdin.readline()
votes = ast.literal_eval(input_str)
num_of_votes = len(votes)
d = {}
for i in votes:
    if i not in d:
        d[i]=1
    else:
        d[i] = d[i]+1

vals = d
winner=False
for value in vals:
    if vals[value]>num_of_votes//2:
        print(value)
        winner=True
        break

if not winner:
    print("NOTA")
```

Comment: This only works if there are always only 2 unique items in the input list.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking at `d.values()` consider using `d.items()`. This will give you the key/value pairs. You can use that in a generator expression and call `next()` to get the value of the key. `next()` takes a default value when there is nothing to return. For example:

```
def winner(votes):
    d = {}
    for i in votes:
        if i not in d:
            d[i]=1
        else:
            d[i] = d[i]+1

    # get the key for a value that's greater than half
    # or NOTA if there isn't one
    return next((k for k, v in d.items() if v > len(votes)//2), 'NOTA')

winner(['a','b','a','a','b','b', 'b'])
# 'b'

winner(['a','b','a','a','b','b'])
# NOTA
```

You should also look at [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) after you've solved it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of occurancies of repeated values as follows:

```
d2 = {}

Input2 = ['a','b','a','a','b','b','b']

# Input 2 
for character in Input2:
    d2[character] = d2.get(character, 0) + 1
# Out[2]: {'a': 3, 'b': 4}
```

To get the winner just use `max()`:
For example: Input 2 winner is:

**`max(d2)` or `max(d2, key=d2.get)` --> 'b' --> 'b' is the winner in the case of Input2

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary is already having the format you need. So I would like to do it this way

```
d = {"a": 3, "b": 5}

if len(set(d.values())) == 1: # check whether all the values are euqal.
    print("NOTA")
else:
    print(max(d, key=d.get))
```

this should do what you need, the best part, you can have more than just a, b, you can have c, and d, :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of keys in the `d` with value equal to the maximum value, and output the winner only if the count is 1:

```
max_votes = max(d.values())
winners = [name for name, votes in d.items() where votes == max_votes]
if len(winners) == 1:
    print(winner[0])
else:
    print('NOTA')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import ast,sys
input_str = sys.stdin.read()
votes = ast.literal_eval(input_str)
my_dict = {}
# Loop to count occurenec of food items
for i in set(votes):
    my_dict[i] = votes.count(i)

# Finding out max votes
max_votes = max(my_dict.values())

# Checking if max votes > half the votes
if max_votes > len(my_dict)//2:
    # Checking if there is no conflicting max votes
    if list(my_dict.values()).count(max_votes) < 2:
        print(list(my_dict.keys())[list(my_dict.values()).index(max_votes)])
    else:
        print('NOTA')
# Default value
else:
    print('NOTA')
```